# Copy one line and paste 5 times in bash linux

Tags: linux, bash, copy, line, paste

need help in copy line in bash..

```
**Input: (input.txt)**

http://localhost.com/123/test.png
http://localhost.com/456/test.png
```

so both line should be pasted 5 times in newfile...
so i want to get below output like this..

```
**Output: (output.txt)**

http://localhost.com/123/test.png
http://localhost.com/123/test.png
http://localhost.com/123/test.png
http://localhost.com/123/test.png
http://localhost.com/123/test.png
http://localhost.com/456/test.png
http://localhost.com/456/test.png
http://localhost.com/456/test.png
http://localhost.com/456/test.png
http://localhost.com/456/test.png
```

So how to possible?
can someone give shell script to make this possible..

Thank you

Comment: You could get more answers from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81904/repeat-each-line-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 sed 'p;p;p;p' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '{for (i=0;i<5;i++) print $NF }' input.txt
```

Comment: @almas it would be better if you change `$NF` to `$0` because your command won't work if a line contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below perl command also.

```
perl -ne 'print "$_"x5' file
```

`$_` is a special variable in Perl which stores the current line like `$0` do in awk. So `"$_"x5` would repeat the current line 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the classic way with loops:

```
while read line; do
  for i in {1..5}; do
    echo "before_text${line}after_text"
  done
done < input.txt
```

Comment: thanx for answer, is there any way to get different suffix in output file..ex:: localhost.com/123/A localhost.com/123/B

Comment: If you know what you want to iterate over, put it in an [array](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html), start your range at 0, and use it to index into the array.